# Delegation pattern vs error handling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, delegates

I am creating a class named `WeatherService` that based on a location will provide the weather forecast (surprise!). There are multiple things that could go wrong here; the location is not found, weather service is not reachable, ...

The service has a method named `weatherFor` taking a `location` object as argument. It is asynchronous.

I am using Swift 2. So I have been reading about error handling in Swift 2.0 and there seems to be one way that multiple sources describe and that is a closure with `ResultType` with a success handler and an error handler. Should I use that? Or should I create a delegate and pass the error like many of the framework objects does such? I already have a delegate for the weather service since I need to know when it starts, when it is done etc.

The delegate protocol has methods like:

- Started weather forecast search
- Ended weather forecast search

But I don't know if I also should add a method in the delegate that is invoked when something bad happens inside the weather service communicating that an error occured and the weather forecast couldn't be found, or if  that is bad? I guess delegates with "error methods" that are invoked isn't bad in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one other object interested in receiving notifications about progress, errors etc you can either go with a closure or delegate. It sort of depends on when and where the errors can occur. If you only need to pass on errors or state when making the `weatherFor` call you can use the closure solution. If errors can happen "anytime", even after - or before - getting the weather, you should use the delegate solution. Or a combination of both.

One other way of doing it is to post notifications when errors occur. This means that more than one object can listen in on updates at the same time.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would do it with a closure? How would it look like with progress updates and error handling?

Comment: That totally depends on how your WeatherService class works and what kind of progress you wish to keep track of

Comment: I added that in my question, when it starts and when it is done.

Comment: Since you already have a delegate set up for this, I suggest you add another delegate method for error handling.

Comment: Okey, and then pass the ErrorType as an argument to it I guess? And is delegation the "old way" while closures are the "new way", or is closures only good to use when there are few outcomes such as success or failure?

Comment: Exactly - pass the error. Delegates or closures totally depends on the situation. Delegates are still a large part of how to handle notifications in iOS and closures aren't a replacement for delegates. Delegates are good for some things, while closures are good for other things.

Comment: Okey, thank you. So is it right to say that closures could be a simpler way of notifing some code to run when there aren't that many callback situations?